# a particle moving around a circle in stochastic process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I have a question that is probably very well known, but I don't quite understand the proof (it is about showing that probability of ending up at a state say i assuming you have visited all the other nodes, so basically i is the last node you ended at when you traversing the circle).

Basically it is page 9 here:
https://www.utsc.utoronto.ca/~sdamouras/courses/STA348H5_F11/Lecture%203%20Annotated.pdf

[image]

My question is I don't quite understand why P(node i visited last | node i-1 visited first before node i+1 visited first) is the same as P(node i visited last | node i+1 visited first before node i-1 visited first), i.e. the $\pi$ probability in the note notation here.

The reason I don't quite understand is because: say if we start at index 0, and say there are total of 1 million states, i.e. m = 1,000,000.

Say now i = 2 (i.e. the last node visited is 2), then I don't quite understand why P(node 2 visited last | node 1 visited first before node 3 visited first) is the same as P(node 2 visited last | node 3 visited first before node 1 visited first).

I thought that to visit node 3 ever for the first time before you visit node 1 for the first time is way more difficult (i.e. much smaller probability) then you visit node 1 ever for the first time before you visit node 3 for the first time IF YOU START from 0 like this question.

Isn't it true that to visit 1 if you start from 0, you have 1/2 probability? (assuming moving clockwise or counter-clockwise has equal probability at any position). But to visit 3 for the first time if you start from 0 before you visit 1 for the first time, isn't it much much less likely? before you have to have visited m=1000000, 999999, 999998, ...., 7, 6, 5,4 before you hit 3?

Comment: "I thought that to visit node 3 ever for the first time before you visit node 1 for the first time is way more difficult (i.e. much smaller probability) then you visit node 1 ever for the first time before you visit node 3." Yes, but that's irrelevant... this is the event you're conditioning on, not the one you're taking the probability of.

Comment: yes, but may I know why the probability of i being the last visited given the condition is the same? (i.e. P(node i visited last | node i-1 visited first before node i+1 visited first) is the same as P(node i visited last | node i+1 visited first before node i-1 visited first))

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it further, I'm not so sure that it's completely clear that getting to one before you get to three is much more likely since it's implicit that you never got to two. (There is a similar possibly false counterintuition here just like in the overall problem where one might find it surprising that you're just as likely to arrive at node 1 last as landing on node 500,000 last.)

Comment: I think if you start at 0, then you are obviously and clearly more likely you hit 1 before you hit 3! Is it not correct?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's true or not and I may be mistaken but it's definitely not obvious to me at present... remember we are only looking at the space where we hit two last. (However, if the question is just "what is the probability you hit one before you hit three?" then yes, it is obvious that that is much higher than the probability of hitting three before one... which is why I quickly agreed with you before thinking about it.)

Comment: but may I know "how" you would hit 3 from 0 assuming hitting 2 last? if you start at 0 and you have 1,000,000 states? you have to go through 1,000,000, 999,999, 999,998,.... 7,6, 5, 4. On the other hand if you were to hit 1 from 0 assuming you hit 2 last, then one way is you just move one spot over.

Comment: but the conditional probability seems make sense to me now if we don't condition on the beginning! Because indeed the professor in the notes here didn't condition on the "beginning position" when he wrote the formula on the slides. He mentioned he would start at 0, but when he actually wrote the formula in the slides, he didn't condition the starting position! I think if he condition on the starting position at zero (i.e. he includes $i_0=0$) in the conditional probability formula in his formula (i.e. the $\pi$), then I guess the two conditional probability will be different. Is it correct?

Comment: Well, the probability of going around to two never hitting one starting from zero is the same as the probability of going around to three never hitting two from one. But anyway this is tangential to the main point... do you understand the answer below?

Comment: No, it’s starting from zero. But you’d get a similar answer starting from any point. (Notice that zero - or whatever the starting point is - is the exception... there’s zero probability that it is the last one you hit of course. All the others have probability 1/m.)

Comment: Umm... not really, I don't fully get it, if we condition on a specific starting position say $X_0=0$

Comment: because I think P(visited 2 last | visit 1 before 3 and starting at 0) seems different from P(visited 2 last | visit 3 before 1 and starting at 0) .

Comment: Ignore what I said about 1 before 3 not being more likely than 3 before 1. The thing about implicitly conditioning on getting to 2 last was just something weird going on in my head, which oddly helped my intuition but doubt will help anyone else's. 1 before 3 is much more likely, just like common sense dictates, full stop, with the probability of the other going roughly like 1/m.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give it another go, and try to be clearer.

Start at zero. Between the two of them, you will either hit 1 or 3 first. Split the sample space into these two options.

As you say, 1 is much more likely. Given that we've hit 1 before we hit 3, what is the probability that 2 is the last node we hit? Well, we haven't hit 2 or 3 yet. If we hit 2 before we hit 3 then we don't hit 2 last. If we hit 3 before 2 then we do hit 2 last, because we haven't hit it yet, and in getting back around to 3, we hit everything else, so 2 is the only thing left and we'll hit it eventually. So our conditional probability that 2 will come last is just the probability of us getting back around the circle to 3 without hitting 2 first. (Which coincidentally will be slightly smaller but close to the probability at the outset of hitting 3 before 1 when we start at 0.)

And what if we hit 3 before we hit 1? What is the probability that 2 is the last node we hit conditional on that? Well... we have to get all the way back around and hit 1 without hitting 2. It's the exact same situation as before in reverse. The probability is exactly the same.

Thus these two conditional probabilities are exactly the same, and they don't depend on $i$ at all. So by the logic explained in the slide, the probability distribution for which node will be last is uniform on $\{1,2,\ldots m\},$ which might be counterintuitive since you might think you have less of a chance of hitting nodes close to zero last since you start nearby them.

---

**old answer**

In both situations, node $i$ is visited last if and only if you make it all the way back around the circle to the unvisited node on the other side of $i$ without visiting $i$ in between. If you do so, you will automatically visit any remaining nodes along the way, so $i$ will be last. If you visit $i$ at any point before visiting the one on the other side, you will not visit $i$ last.

These two situations are perfectly symmetrical, so regardless of the relative likelihood of getting in one or the other states (and you're correct... in your example one is much more likely than the other), the conditional probability of visiting $i$ last is the same.

Comment: I understand the symmetric argument. The thing I don't understand is why is it NOT that:  P(visited 2 last | visit 1 before 3 and starting at 0) is different from P(visited 2 last | visit 3 before 1 and starting at 0)

Comment: @john_w But the symmetric argument is an argument for exactly this. I'm not sure how much better I can do than what I wrote above, but I'll try.

Comment: @john_w Ok, gave it another shot.

Comment: Hi, I perfectly understand your two cases. Yes they are symmetric just like say if hitting 5 before 7 (and hitting 6 last) or 7 before 5 (and hitting 6 last)... or i before i +2 (and hitting i +1 last) or i + 2 before i (and hitting i last).   But I guess the two splitting case have the same conditional distribution because they didn't condition on the starting position. If we include the starting position in the conditional probability, then I think P(hitting i last | hitting i -1 before hitting i+1 and starting at 0) is not the same as P(hitting i last | hitting i -1 before hitting i+1).

Comment: Sorry I understand your two cases perfectly I think, but I still not quite sure or can understand how conditioning on the starting position has no effect on the probability of hitting i last. Because the professor who wrote this note also "seem to forget" or maybe he include "conditional on starting at zero" implicitly in the formula he wrote there? But I still think  P(hitting i last | hitting i -1 before hitting i+1 and starting at 0) is not the same as P(hitting i last | hitting i -1 before hitting i+1).

Comment: Because you mentioned in your comment that "starting at zero" is part of the condition in the conditional probability. But I think this is the most important thing that I don't understand.

Comment: Because to me it seems that P(hitting i last | hitting i -1 before hitting i+1 and starting at 0) is not the same as P(hitting i last | hitting i -1 before hitting i+1).

Comment: If we didn't condition at the starting position say starting at zero, then I think the symmetric argument holds and I can understand. So  P(hitting i last | hitting i -1 before hitting i+1 ) is equal to  P(hitting i last | hitting i +1 before hitting i-1).

Comment: @john_w The entire goal and point of the answer is to explain why it is. We are computing the conditional probability  (given that we start from zero).

Comment: sorry, could you explain what you mean by "The entire goal and point of the answer is to explain why it is" ? could you elaborate little bit more. Sorry I lost the meaning because I added too many comments after your last comment.

Comment: Why the conditional probabilities that you don’t think are the same, are in fact the same.

Comment: Hello, sorry are you referring to these two conditional probabilities: P(hitting i last | hitting i +1 before hitting i-1 ) ,  P(hitting i last | hitting i +1 before hitting i-1 given starting at 0)  ?  i.e. the condition probability of including the information of starting at 0 is the same as the conditional probability without this piece of information?  Sorry I just want to confirm.

Comment: @john_w Yes, that's what I mean. (Provided $i$ is not zero, of course.)

Comment: (Actually, it's a bit more complicated, cause you could pick the starting point the same as $i$. Let's just say those two conditional probabilities the same given there is a fixed starting point... if you happen to pick the starting point equal to $i$, then they're both zero... still the same, but not the same as the other choices of starting point in which case they are both $1/m$.)